# Mysql cambiar numero de semana

Tags: mysql

me podrian ayudar por favor,
tengo estos registros que tienen el numero de semana.

```
semana
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

pero quisiera cambiarlas asi;

```
42->1
43->2
44->3
...
...
...
52->11
1->12
2->13
3->14
```

como lo podria hacer?

Comment: Por favor no te olvides de compartir lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿No ves un patrón ahí? Algo así como que le estás **restando 41 a todos los valores mayores a 41**... y le **sumas 11 a todos los que sean menores a 41**.

Esto, lo sé bien, debería ponerlo como comentario (aún no tengo suficiente "reputación" para ello). Pero tampoco quisiera "hacerte la tarea". Creo que me iré a un punto medio y te describiré el pseudo-código que te propongo como solución

```
actualiza semana con (semana-11) si semana es mayor a 41;
```

y, posteriormente

```
actualiza semana con (semana + 11) si semana es menor a 41;
```

Por favor, comenta si has dado con la solución. Un saludo.

Comment: hola, si gracias con eso me ayudaste, saludos